# What types of languages are supported in Xcode build phases run script?

Tags: xcode, scripting, run-script, scripting-languages

I am new to scripting but I need to learn it for a script I need to run in the build phases of an Xcode project.

What types of scripts can I write in there? What types of languages are supported? Is there one scripting language easier to learn than others?

Just looking to get a point in the right direction here.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer would likely be: "a script that works in any shell that comes with MacOS"

On my Mountain Lion machine, I see:

```
[/]:; more /etc/shells
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
```

You can specify the shell you want in the "Shell" field of the Run Script panel when you're creating your build script.  It looks like this:

[image: Enter The Shell Here]